# What EXIF lib can I use from a Qt program (on embedded linux)?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, metadata, exif

Can anybody recommend a nice exif lib for tiff img that can be used with a Qt program? 
I would like to both read and write exif data.

Please note that that I need a license that is compatible with a closed source program, 
so a lib that is using LGPL or a BSD style license would be really nice.

My first plan was to use [QExifImageHeader](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtextended4.4/qexifimageheader.html) and [QExifValue](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtextended4.4/qexifvalue.html) in Qt Extended, 
but then I noticed that Extended never got the LGPL licence and is on top of that it is [discontinued](http://qt.nokia.com/about/news/qt-software-discontinues-qt-extended)....

The platform used is Embedded linux.

Thanks
Johan

---

*Update*:

Since I'm adding a bounty for this question, 
I'm refining the question to be about to add exif data 
on a tiff image from a Qt program.

A nice lib to use and a example on how to use it would be really nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if it is not Qt-related, probably your best option is the [libexif C EXIF library](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/). It is a GNOME core library (thus is widely deployed, tested and documented), still it is completely toolkit-agnostic, has no dependences and is LGPL licensed. It is a C library, thus its API is not idiomatic of Qt, nonetheless it is powerful and easy to use.

I've seen a lot of Qt-based software that prefer to use the [exiv2 library](http://www.exiv2.org/), which is written in C++, but exiv2 is GPL (with option to buy a commercial license) and offers more or less the same functionality of libexif. My suggestion is to try libexif and, only if it does not satisfy your requirements, try exiv2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [libjpeg-exif](http://fink.cvs.sourceforge.net/fink/dists/10.4/unstable/main/finkinfo/graphics/libjpeg-exif.info?view=markup) library, it includes tools manipulate and read EXIF data.