# QImage loads with wrong orientation for certain images

Tags: qt

I am instantiating a QImage from an image file like below and subsequently rendering it on a QWidget.

```
QImage ( const QString & fileName, const char * format = 0 )
```

For most images, everything works fine. But for a few images, the QImage gets loaded with a 90-degree rotated image.

It seems this happens only with pictures taken earlier on my phone in portrait mode. Those taken in landscape are fine

Comment: Maybe the images contain some meta data about the orientation and the image viewers you are using rotate the image according to that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use a library like libexif to determine the photo orientation and then rotate the QImage accordingly

Comment: Do you know which `libexif` API tells photo orientation? Better still is there a library built into Qt that can do the job?

Comment: @SaptarshiBiswas I looked briefly and it doesn't look like Qt handles exif. The property for rotation in exif is called orientation I believe. libexif is a pretty simple library to use and has a very open license. It's easy to integrate into existing projects.

Answer (score 5):

With C++ Qt-class QImageReader:

```
QImageReader imgReader( imagePath );
imgReader.setAutoTransform( true );
QImage img = imgReader.read();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Qt 5.5 set **Image.autoTransform : true** because the default is false!

[QT Image QML Type reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#autoTransform-prop)

Comment: Thank you. This helped me find QImageReader::setAutoTransform(). See my separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2541504?start=0&tstart=0

It sounds like it is a pretty common issue, where there is some flag or tag added on the image that says how to rotate it, instead of actually reordering the pixels in the image.  For the image you are trying to render, you could go and take the format you are trying to use, and see if there are any extra flags you could check and have Qt do the rotation.

Sounds like cppguy knows of a library that can let you check these flags.

EDIT Found a better description for it:

> johninsj  -  Re: iPhone 4 Photo's & Video Rotating Sideways In Email
>
> Nov 2, 2010 1:45 PM (in response to VibrantRedGT)
>
> Apple sets the jpeg meta tag for orientation when you shoot a photo,
>   so if you hold the iphone upside down, or sideways, etc, the image
>   (which is shot upside down or sideways, since the camera is upside
>   down/sideways) knows it needs to flip/rotate the image when you look
>   at it.
>
> Not all software honors the rotation settings. Gimp (which runs on
>   everything, and is free) does.
>
> You can rotate images and save them, or learn to shoot photos with the
>   iPhone in the correct orientation for non-rotated images. That would
>   be with the home button to the right as you look at the screen.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Is there a way to read exif in Qt instead of using external libraries as cppguy suggested?

Comment: These two questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128656/read-exif-metadata-of-images-in-qt  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105534/what-exif-lib-can-i-use-from-a-qt-program-on-embedded-linux?rq=1 may help. It looks like there is something, that you can add on: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtextended4.4/qexifimageheader.html

Comment: Since QExifImageHeader is not a part of Qt, I was doubtful about its support and maintenance aspects - so I went with libexif as cppguy suggested.