# Read exif metadata of images in Qt

Tags: qt, exif

In my Qt app I want to read exif data of images. `QImage` or `QPixmap` don't seem to provide such hooks.

Is there any API in Qt that allows reading exif without using external libraries like `libexif`?

EDIT: This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105534/what-exif-lib-can-i-use-from-a-qt-program-on-embedded-linux?rq=1)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105534/what-exif-lib-can-i-use-from-a-qt-program-on-embedded-linux?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

For me, the best choice was [easyexif by Mayank Lahiri](https://github.com/mayanklahiri/easyexif). You only need to add two files exif.cpp and exif.h to your project.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i=1; i<argc; ++i){
        QFile file(argv[i]);
        if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
            QByteArray data = file.readAll();
            easyexif::EXIFInfo info;
            if (int code = info.parseFrom((unsigned char *)data.data(), data.size())){
                qDebug() << "Error parsing EXIF: code " << code;
                continue;
            }
            qDebug() << "Camera model         : " << info.Model.c_str();
            qDebug() << "Original date/time   : " << info.DateTimeOriginal.c_str();
        } else
            qDebug() << "Can't open file:" << argv[i];           
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only works for JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

Try [QExifImageHeader](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtextended4.4/qexifimageheader.html) from qt extended framework. qtextended.org is not available for me? but you may search for other download mirrows.