# Sort files in a QDir by exif data in QT (Cross platform)

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, exif

I need to sort the contents of a QDir using the exif date (The time the picture was taken).

Now since most cameras name the photos sequentially I can achieve the sorting I want with `myQDir.setSorting(QDir::Name)`, but if the camera resets it's count or I have images from two or more cameras in the same folder, I can't.

`QDir::Time` does not work either, because it's the time the picture was copied from the camera to the PC.

My program will run on windows and linux so I need a cross platform solution.

I've found [easyexif](https://github.com/mayanklahiri/easyexif) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46687923/2974608) but I don't know how to achieve what I want with it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with: `myQDir.setSorting(QDir::Time);`

Comment: @eyllanesc I forgot to mention it in the question but I've already tried this.
Check the updated answer.

Comment: so that you use QDir exactly, since I see that the ordering is in a private class and I find it difficult to overwrite that method. Maybe we can give another option.

Comment: What other option? I use QDir because the application is in qt environment and I want it cross platform.

Comment: I do not mean that, maybe if I know the task you want to do, I might suggest another kind of Qt.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/gramanas/rrwc/tree/multiThreadOutputs) is the project. I use the QDir in the `enginemanager.cpp` to  get a list of all the images inside the folder. I want exif date sort so it will be usable in real life scenarios.

Comment: Do you want the paths stored in the variable `allFiles` to be sorted with that criterion?

Comment: Yeah! That's the one!

Comment: Your code can be executed or still have problems? Every time I execute it, it generates a SIGARBT error, or indicates the procedure to use it.

Comment: For me it works just fine :/ I am on linux tho

Comment: @TheGramm. I suppose you could use a `QFileSystemModel` with a `QSortFilterProxyModel` subclass that reimplements [lessThan](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan). This would just need to return the result of comparing two exif `DateTimeOriginal` values (which could be converted to `QDateTime` first).